# get_post_meta returns 0

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to get metadata for a post (of custom post type). I had a look in the database, and the table "wp_postmeta" holds a row with "post_id" = 65, "meta_key" = "name_text" and "meta_value" = "Lars Åkerkvist".

I am trying to fetch that value, Lars Åkerkvist, using get_post_meta as below

```
get_post_meta(65,"name_text",true)
```

But it always returns a 0. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: First thing, you probably want to get your accept rate up or people will be disinclined to answer your question, you have 7 questions with 0 accepted answers between them, which doesn't bode well for you. Secondly, `0` is not a valid return from `get_post_meta()` unless it is the value which is stored in there. It returns an empty string on failure.

Comment: That was really bad of me, i must have forgot that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$single` back to `false`, e.g.:

```
<?php $name_text = get_post_meta( 65, 'name_text' ); ?>
```

[Why?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

> If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a **string**. If false, or not set, then the function returns an **array** of the custom fields. This is not intuitive. For example, if you fetch a serialized array with this method you want $single to be true to actually get an unserialized array back. If you pass in false, or leave it out, you will have an array of one, and the value at index 0 will be the serialized string.

You want to return the **array**, and then use `$name_text[0]`.

Comment: I tried that now, but ran into a weird issue. If i do print_r on $name_text, i get the following result

    Array ( [0] => Anton Gildebrand ) 1

But if i do it like this
$name_text[0], i get a 0 only

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had accidently used the plus sign instead of dots when concatenating strings...